# Problems with Sidebars and #pusher in Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please, help me with this issue.

I have a sctructure.

```html
<div id="toolbar" class="toolbar overlay-displace-top clearfix toolbar-processed">
...
</div>
<div class="ui left sidebar vertical inverted menu overlay" id="ls">
...
 </div>


<div class="ui right sidebar vertical inverted menu overlay" id="rs">
...
</div>
<div class="ui fixed top attached inverted menu">
...
</div>


<div id="page">
...
</div>
```

When I am clicking on toggle button, I am having problems... Semantic-ui puts all divs to #pusher without #ls and top fixed menu.
Administration toolbar is invisible, because is inside #pusher.

I don't want #rs and toolbar inside #pusher.

```html
<div class="ui left sidebar vertical inverted menu overlay" id="ls">
...
 </div>
<div id="pusher">


  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#middle-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>


  <div id="toolbar" class="toolbar overlay-displace-top clearfix toolbar-processed">
  ...
  </div>


  <div class="ui right sidebar vertical inverted menu overlay" id="rs">
  ...
  </div>


</div>


<div class="ui fixed top attached inverted menu">
...
</div>
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I see you have two divs named "ls", I assume the second one was meant to be called "rs", that would be why it is moved into #pusher

Answer (score 0):

We needs add class "Pusher" instead id. Thats all.